# Yocto Install and Use Toaster

Tags: linux, yocto, bitbake, openembedded

I'm successfully using Yocto to build an embedded system targeting a TI EVM platform. I can bitbake my image using command line or the Hob GUI interface.

Now I am trying to install and use Toaster. I've following the Yocto Wiki to a tee without errors:
https://wiki.yoctoproject.org/wiki/Setting_up_a_production_instance_of_Toaster

I also have their recommended script running in the background:

```
#!/bin/sh
# toaster run builds dispatcher
cd /var/www/toaster/
source ./venv/bin/activate
while true; do ./poky/bitbake/lib/toaster/manage.py runbuilds; sleep 3; done
```

Now I see the following output from Toaster in Firefox:

[image]

At the bottom it says: " Toaster has not recorded any builds yet. Go build something with Knotty or Hob ", so I went and did another build that finished successfully with Hob.

[image]

What gives? Why does Toaster did not see my new build ( or any build ) ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might be using Yocto Project 1.8 (Fido). In theory, Toaster running in analysis mode

http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/1.8.1/toaster-manual/toaster-manual.html#using-toaster-in-analysis-mode

should pick up the builds you run with Hob, but you must start Toaster before running your build.

There is also a chance Toaster is simply not interacting well with Hob. If you run the build with Knotty

bitbake your-image

does the build information appear in Toaster?

If you want to build Yocto Project 1.8 (Fido), you could also clone Yocto Project 2.0 (Jethro) and run your builds from Toaster. Simply select the Yocto Project 1.8 release when creating a Toaster project.

Comment: Hob is obsolete.  Yocto Developers are not working on it anymore.  I recommend you to not learn to use it.